# NullReferenceException error occured when clicked on the Column header of the DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, nullreferenceexception

I am using a `DataGridView` control in WinForm. When I click the ColumnHeader an Exception was met. it points to the line:

```
 m_iSWId = Convert.ToInt32(DataGViewDetails.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString()
```

i am getting `NullReferenceException`

How to solve this?

Comment: That could be `CurrentRow` which is null, or the `Cell[8]` which doesn't exist

Comment: How many columns are on your grid? I think the index is zero-based.

Comment: @Habib you are right , the CurrentRow is null,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `CurrentRow` [selects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentrow.aspx) only rows not columns(column headers)

Assuming you are doing this in `DataGridView_Click` Event, Wrap your code with the below one:

```
if(e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
{     
     //Your code here   
}
```

Comment: private void DataGViewDetails_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
             
            // {
            //    m_iSWId = Convert.ToInt32(DataGViewStation.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString());
         

            if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
            {
                m_iSWId = Convert.ToInt32(DataGViewStation.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString());
             }
        }

Comment: if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)

Comment: @user1495331 The code you are using also ignores `RowHeader`'s If that is what you want then its alright. Have a nice day :)

Comment: do u mean   e.RowIndex>=0 && e.ColumnIndex>=0 ??

Comment: Yes, The RowIndex of `RowHeader` is `-1` whereas the ColumnIndex of `ColumnHeader` is `-1`. here you mentioning both `RowIndex and ColumnIndex`. So the code you are trying will not allow clicking to both `RowHeader` and `ColumnHeader`.

Comment: @user1495331 If this post solved your issue then mark it as accepted answer. and upvote(optional).